# How can I return to the main menu?

Tags: java, menu

I have a project that I want it to go back to the first menu if it is selected from the second menu.

The following is just an example:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SAMPLE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

This is the first menu:

```
    System.out.println("Enter choice: ");
    System.out.println("1 = A");
    System.out.println("2 = B");
    int choice1 = input.nextInt();

    do {
```

This is the second menu:

```
        System.out.println("Another choice:");
        System.out.println("1 = C");
        System.out.println("2 = D");
        System.out.println("3 = Go back");
        int choice2 = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice2) {
        case 1: System.out.println("nice");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("nicee");
            break;
```

If I selected 3, it should go back to the first menu but I don't know how.

```
        case 3: System.out.println("How can I go back to the first menu? HELP!");
            break;
        }

    } while (choice1 > 2);

    System.out.println("END OF THE PROGRAM");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest splitting your code into functions.

Upon case 3 - You shall call your new function.

Something like this:

```
static int mainMenu(Scanner inputScanner)
{
System.out.println("Enter choice: ");
System.out.println("1 = A");
System.out.println("2 = B");
return inputScanner.nextInt(); //Assume valid input. you should add a valid check
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

int Choice1  = mainMenu(input);
do { 

    System.out.println("Another choice:");
    System.out.println("1 = C");
    System.out.println("2 = D");
    System.out.println("3 = Go back");
    int Choice2 = input.nextInt();

    switch (Choice2) {
    case 1: //DO Y
        break;
    case 2: //DO X
        break; 
    case 3: Choice1 = mainMenu(input);
        break;
    }

} while (Choice1 > 2); 
//END logic
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aha You want to go back to the first menu of choosing A and B in the process of choosing C and D!

There are many ways(such as use another method or recursion), 
but I recommend this method which will be easier to understand now.

First, Let's check the code to organize what we want to do
<*I changed it slightly to make it more recognizable! I'm sorry!*>

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOver {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  ////main_menu///-Select A or B
  System.out.println("Please input Enter Choice: ");
  System.out.println("input '1' to Select A");
  System.out.println("input '2' to Select B");
  int choice1 = input.nextInt();
  ////////////////////////////


  ////second_Menu Choose C or D, or Back to main_menu
  System.out.println("Another choice: ");
  System.out.println("input '1' to Select C");
  System.out.println("input '2' to Select D");
  System.out.println("input '3' to Go back");
  int choice2 = input.nextInt();


  //According to 'choice2'
  switch(choice2) {
  case 1: System.out.println("nice, you Select C");
     break;
  case 2: System.out.println("nicee, you Select D");
     break;

  case 3: System.out.println("Now, you can go to Back");
     break;
  }
  //I'm sorry, but I can't understand the meaning of 
  //'while (choice1 > 2);' ㅠㅅㅠ

  System.out.println("END OF THE PROGRAM");
  }

}
```

So the code above is the one you asked for, right?

There are so many ways to implement it in the direction you want.

Let's try to get it back to the main menu through the While statement you were trying to use.

The code progresses.

1. **(1)** Choosing A and B
2. **(2)** Choosing C and D or (1)

It consists of going to (1) or ending the program, depending on the result of (2).

how about use do{ }while(boolean);??
The process in do{} will continue until 'boolean' is false.

now We can change code in this way

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice2 = 0; //init for NullPointerError


    do {
    //below do{
    ////main_menu///-Select A or B
        System.out.println("Please input Enter Choice: ");
        System.out.println("input '1' to Select A");
        System.out.println("input '2' to Select B");
        int choice1 = input.nextInt();
        ////////////////////////////


        ////second_Menu Choose C or D, or Back to main_menu
        System.out.println("Another choice: ");
        System.out.println("input '1' to Select C");
        System.out.println("input '2' to Select D");
        System.out.println("input '3' to Go back");
        choice2 = input.nextInt();


        //According to 'choice2'
        switch(choice2) {
        case 1: System.out.println("nice, you Select C");
            break;
        case 2: System.out.println("nicee, you Select D");
            break;

        case 3: System.out.println("Now, you can go to Back");
            break;
        }

    }while(choice2 == 3);
    //if choice2 == 3, then the progress of code return back to below 'do{'

    System.out.println("END OF THE PROGRAM");
    }

}
```

This is the result of the changed code.
[image]

I hope you understood it well and If there's anything that's hard to understand, please leave a comment!
I hope you have a pleasant and peaceful day today.

Comment: I'm glad for this answer could you give a little help! Have a nice day